# Is it possible to

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome-extension, web-applications

Writing a web app in node/express that serves "office" files (xlsx, docx, etc.) and displays them using Chrome's [Office Editing extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en-GB).

On rare occasions, one of the files needs to be modified and saved. But the chrome extension only seems to support two ways of saving files:

- save to google drive (google docs)
- save to the local file system

I want to write a PUT handler to receive the modified file from the browser and overwrite the original file. Does the chrome extension support PUTing (or POSTing) the modified file back to the original URL? I cannot find any documentation to show that the extension supports putting the file, so my guess is that the answer is no. But it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: For a Chrome extension, I think it's safe to say that if it's not in the docs, then it's not there. You're probably going to need to use a 3rd-party rich-text editor library to provide this functionality, rather than the Chrome extension.